# data grid selection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

how can i do in DataGrid after mouse right button click actual item under mouse will select (same as mouse left button click)
thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to extend your `DataGrid` and introduce there a new field:

```
public var currentOverItem:Object;
```

Then override `mouseOverHandler()` in your custom `DataGrid` the following way:

```
    override protected function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        super.mouseOverHandler(event);
        var item:IListItemRenderer = mouseEventToItemRenderer(event);
        if (item)
        {
            currentOverItem = item.data;
        }
        else
        {
            currentOverItem = null;
        }
    }
```

Using of this DataGrid is pretty simple. Just subscribe `ContextMenuEvent.MENU_SELECT` event of the instance of your custom `DataGrid` and use the following code in context menu handler:

```
            myGrid.selectedItem = myGrid.currentOverItem;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i find event itemRollOver so i make handler 

> protected function myGrid_itemRollOverHandler(event:ListEvent):void
{
event.target.selectedIndex = event.rowIndex;
}

Comment: Yes, it will work. I've just offered encapsulated solution :)